# CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE using Intel(R)Xeon(R)Gold 6240 CPU

Tags: windows, opencl, intel

I get the error CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE when debugging an openCL exe.And the cpu is Intel(R)Xeon(R)Gold 6240 CPU@2.60GHz(32 processors),and I have installed cl_runtime_14.2_x86_setup.msi.Is there something lost? And which tool can debug inside the kernel code of openCL?

Comment: Try running known good OpenCL programs to check if it's your program or the OpenCL environment that's at fault. I suggest you try to run clinfo as a start. OpenCL devices require the appropriate platform to be installed or else it probably won't even find your device.

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether the problem is with the application or with the OpenCL runtime installation, try running the [OpenCL-Benchmark](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Benchmark/releases/tag/v1.2). If this says there is no OpenCL devices, then the runtime installation is not working.

The [Intel OpenCL CPU Runtime](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-cpu-runtime-for-opencl-applications-with-sycl-support.html) installer in current version `w_opencl_runtime_p_2024.0.0.49848.exe` is bugged such that after installation, the CPU does not show up as OpenCL device. To get it working, a modification in registry keys is necessary:

- press<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>; the Registry Editor will open
- in the path text field, enter `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors`

  - richt click, `New`-->`DWORD-Value (32-bit)`
  - name it `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\bin\intelocl64.dll`
  - leave its value at 0 (Hexadecimal)
- in the path text field, enter `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors`

  - richt click, `New`-->`DWORD-Value (32-bit)`
  - name it `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\bin\intelocl64.dll`
  - leave its value at 0 (Hexadecimal)
- in the path text field, enter `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors`

  - richt click, `New`-->`DWORD-Value (32-bit)`
  - name it `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\bin32\intelocl32.dll`
  - leave its value at 0 (Hexadecimal)
- close Registry Editor
- reboot
- the CPU should now show up as OpenCL device

Comment: thanks a lot, I follow these steps to intall the w_opencl_runtime_p_2024.0.0.49848.exe, the error  api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll is missing,so I put the dll to the .exe folder, it works succefully.By the way,Which tool can debug the kernel code? I known the Kernel Builder can make it, but cannot find the package about it.